# How can I locate the cell in a table using Protractor

Tags: javascript, html, angular, protractor

I want to locate the flight number (11302) on the table using protractor. And then click the button which is inserted into the same row.

```html
<kendo-grid-list role="presentation" class="k-grid-container ng-star-inserted">
  <!---->
  <div role="presentation" tabindex="-1" class="k-grid-content k-virtual-content">
    <div role="presentation" class="k-grid-table-wrap">
      <table role="presentation" class="k-grid-table">
        <colgroup kendogridcolgroup="" role="presentation">
          <col style="width: 40px;" class="ng-star-inserted">
          <col style="width: 90px;" class="ng-star-inserted">
          <col style="width: 120px;" class="ng-star-inserted">
          <col style="width: 120px;" class="ng-star-inserted">
          <col style="width: 50px;" class="ng-star-inserted">
          <col style="width: 100px;" class="ng-star-inserted">
        </colgroup>
        <tbody kendogridtablebody="" role="presentation">

          <tr kendogridlogicalrow="" data-kendo-grid-item-index="0" role="row" class="ng-star-inserted" style="">
            <td kendogridcell="" kendogridlogicalcell="" role="gridcell" aria-selected="false" data-kendo-grid-column-index="0" colspan="1" aria-colindex="1" class="ng-star-inserted">
              <button _ngcontent-wqs-c341="" kendobutton="" look="flat" icon="plus-circle" class="k-button-icon k-button k-primary k-flat ng-star-inserted" role="button" aria-disabled="false" aria-pressed="false" dir="ltr"><span _ngcontent-wqs-c341="" class="k-icon k-i-plus-circle ng-star-inserted" role="presentation"></span></button>
            </td>
            <td kendogridcell="" kendogridlogicalcell="" role="gridcell" aria-selected="false" data-kendo-grid-column-index="1" colspan="1" aria-colindex="2" class="ng-star-inserted">
              <a _ngcontent-wqs-c341="" href="/admin/manifest-detail/27513" class="ng-star-inserted"> 11302</a>
              <br _ngcontent-wqs-c341="" class="ng-star-inserted">
              <span _ngcontent-wqs-c341="" title="" class="ng-star-inserted">Open </span>
            </td>
            <td kendogridcell="" kendogridlogicalcell="" role="gridcell" aria-selected="false" data-kendo-grid-column-index="2" colspan="1" aria-colindex="3" class="ng-star-inserted">
              07:00 AM<br _ngcontent-wqs-c341="" class="ng-star-inserted"> Midland, MI
            </td>
```

I tried to locate the element using by.css, which is shown as following

```js
let temp2 = element(by.css(".k-grid-container .data-kendo-grid-item-index='0' .data-kendo-grid-column-index='1'")).element(by.tagName('a'));
```

So far I cannot locate the cell where a flight number is in, not alone to click the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case I would probably just select the row like this:

```
let row = element(by.css(".k-grid-container tr[data-kendo-grid-item-index='0']";
```

and then perform your action on the link and the button like this:

```
expect(row.element(by.tagName('a')).getText()).toContain("11302");
row.element(by.tagName('button')).click();
```

The by.tagName() function selects the first child of row with a tagname a, so you don't necessarily need to specify which td to look in. If the data-kendo-grid-item-index attribute doesn't show up in the final page, you could also select the row by the order they appear in:

```
let row = element.all(by.css(".k-grid-container tr").first();
```

Your first approach

```js
let temp2 = element(by.css(".k-grid-container .data-kendo-grid-item-index='0' .data-kendo-grid-column-index='1'")).element(by.tagName('a'));
```

probably didn't work because you looked for data-kendo-grid-item-index as a class name, rather than an attribute.

If you are testing on an Angular page, you don't need to manually wait for the tests to find specific items on your page with .then(...), as it automatically syncs with Angular.

Answer (score 0):

I tried another way, and here is the code

```js
element.all(by.tagName('tbody')).first().then(function(_table) {
  return _table.element(by.tagName('tr')).filter(function(_tableRow) {
    return _tableRow.element.all(by.tagName('td')).get(1).then(function(_tableCell) {
      let tmp = _tableCell.element(by.tagName('a'));
      return expect(tmp.getText()).toContain("11302");
    });
  }).first().element(by.tagName('button')).click();
});
```

I have totally 3 tables ('tbody') on the page, and the index of the cell contains flight number is always the 1. But it failed and the report is

> - Failed: protractor_1.element.all(...).first(...).then is not a function